# MySQL select rows where cell value equals number where non-digit characters are dropped

Tags: php, mysql, regex

**Problem**: some product sku look like this "67062-4D" or "MOD602-04-N". So task is to find sku by its digits when user uses search, e.g. "67062-4D" by "670624" and "MOD123-45-N" by "12345".
**Solution**: I managed to solve this by repeting [^0-9]*1 in php to create a regexp (php and mysql is in use), but realy want to know if where is a universal or more natural solution. Otherwise just posting this solution.
This example finds "MOD123-45-N"

```
SELECT product_id WHERE sku REGEXP '^[^0-9]*1[^0-9]*2[^0-9]*3[^0-9]*4[^0-9]*5[^0-9]*$'
```

update: 
version 10.1.40-MariaDB

Comment: Which version of MySQL?

Comment: 10.1.40-MariaDB

Comment: Your regex is not doing what you think it is doing. Also: https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/like/

Comment: I believe it does. Counterexample?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [`REGEXP_REPLACE`](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/regexp_replace/) to remove all non-digit characters from the string and then compare it to the input number e.g.

```
SELECT product_id WHERE REGEXP_REPLACE(sku, '[^0-9]', '') = '12345'
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.2&fiddle=ca0c19147e8ce80182ce4c56ec6b2816)

Answer (score 0):

With `regexp_replace()`:

```
select product_id 
from tablename
where regexp_replace(sku, '\\D', '') LIKE concat('%', search, '%')
```

or to find exact match:

```
select product_id 
from tablename
where regexp_replace(sku, '\\D', '') = search
```

Comment: I've never seen \\D before. Does '\\D' means '[^0-9]'?

Comment: Exactly, everything that is not a digit.

Comment: Thank you, but I have to accept only 1 answear and I believe Nick was the first.